# Finding RSA parameters

Tags: java, android, rsa

I would like to find the c, d, p and q parameters in this code that I am using for an android project demonstration.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Key_distribution

This is my code

```
public class RSA {
    private final static String RSA = "RSA";

    public static PublicKey puk;
    public static PrivateKey prk;


    public static void generateKey() throws Exception {
        KeyPairGenerator gen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(RSA);
        gen.initialize(512, new SecureRandom());
        KeyPair keyPair = gen.generateKeyPair();
        puk = keyPair.getPublic();
        prk = keyPair.getPrivate();

    }
}
```

Please how can I get these values from this code?

Comment: check the dynamic type of the returned public and private key. Should be something like `RSAPublicKey` and `RSAPrivateKey`, then you can cast to that type and access the parameters.

Comment: I've read this online but I am failing to convert them to a String in order to display them in a textview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't remember the exact mapping but you can access all values if you cast public and private keys to their RSA specific types:

```
    RSAPublicKey puk = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
    RSAPrivateCrtKey prk = (RSAPrivateCrtKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
    System.out.println("p: " + prk.getPrimeP());
    System.out.println("q: " + prk.getPrimeQ());
    ...
```

See [RSAPublicKey](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/interfaces/RSAPublicKey.html) and [RSAPrivateCrtKey](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/interfaces/RSAPrivateCrtKey.html)

Comment: Thanks, I will try it and see the result